# Multiple OAuth2Introspection schemes to validate the token, want to allow execution if one the token validation check pass

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, introspection

I am trying to validate the token with multiple clients and if any of them passes the validation, I need to allow the execution of the request. Here's my code, it's working fine, but if one of them fails, it logs the error. Having the ability to ignore error logging when one of the authentications passes validation would be helpful. if no one pass then logging the error is perfectly okay to me.

I need an ability to ignore the error message logging when one of the client validation passes.
Is my approach okay to validate tokens in case of multiple clients?

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could suggest if I am doing something wrong.

I have attached my code here

```
services
  .AddFunctionsAuthentication(options => options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[] {
      "Audience1",
      "Audience2"
    };

    options.Authority = Appsettings.AuthIdentityUrl;

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidTypes = new [] {
      "at+jwt",
      "JWT"
    };

    // if token does not contain a dot, it is a reference token
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = Auth.ForwardReferenceToken("introspection1");

  })
  .AddOAuth2Introspection("introspection1", options => {
    options.Authority = Appsettings.AuthIdentityUrl;

    options.ClientId = AppSettings.AuthClientId1;
    options.ClientSecret = AppSettings.AuthClientSecret1;
  }).AddOAuth2Introspection("introspection2", options => {
    options.Authority = Appsettings.AuthIdentityUrl;

    options.ClientId = AppSettings.AuthClientId2;
    options.ClientSecret = AppSettings.AuthClientSecret2;
  });
```

This is what i tries till now, I am expecting ignore the error message logging when one of the client validation passes.

Comment: what's services.AddFunctionsAuthentication?what product are you tring with?

Comment: https://github.com/dark-loop/functions-authorize for azure functions Authorization